# Delegate method not being called or not firing when called

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to implement two delegate methods. I think I have the protocol written correctly, and that I'm assigning the delegate correctly, as I modeled it carefully on another delegate/protocol that works fine. However, the delegate methods don't fire when called, or at least that appears to be what's happening. I've set breakpoints in the places where the delegate methods are called, and also at the methods themselves, but it seems that control never reaches them.

Here's what I believe to be the relevant code. From the notifyingVC.h file:

```
//  AddCategoryVC.h
//  YYYYYY
//
//  Created by XXXXXX on 2/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 XXXXXX. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "WMMGCategory.h"
//#import "AddTransactionVC.h"

@class AddTransactionVC;

@protocol AddCategoryDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) addCategoryDidSave : (WMMGCategory *) brandNewCategory;

-(void) addCategoryDidCancel : (WMMGCategory *) categoryToDelete;

@end

@interface AddCategoryVC : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <AddCategoryDelegate> delegate;
```

From the notifyingVC.m file:

```
//  AddCategoryVC.m
//  YYYYYY
//
//  Created by XXXXXX on 2/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 XXXXXX. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AddCategoryVC.h"
#import "WMMGCategory.h"

@interface AddCategoryVC ()


@end


@implementation AddCategoryVC

…Blah de blah…

- (IBAction)saveCategory:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    if (self.nooCatTextField.text.length < 1)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New category not identified"
                                                        message:@"Please enter a name for the new category or cancel"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    else
    {
        self.brandNewCategory.name = [self.nooCatTextField.text uppercaseString];
        [self.delegate addCategoryDidSave:self.brandNewCategory];
    }

}

- (IBAction)cancelCategory:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.delegate addCategoryDidCancel:self.brandNewCategory];
}
```

From the DelegateVC.h file:

```
//
//  AddTransactionVC.h
//  YYYYYY
//
//  Created by XXXXXX on 2/6/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 XXXXXX. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MagicalRecord/CoreData+MagicalRecord.h>

#import "WMMGTransaction.h"
#import "AddCategoryVC.h"
#import "WMMGCategory.h"
```

From the DelegateVC.m header:

```
//
//  AddTransactionVC.m
//  YYYYYY
//
//  Created by XXXXXXXX on 2/6/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 XXXXXX. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AddTransactionVC.h"

@interface AddTransactionVC ()

@end

@implementation AddTransactionVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    AddCategoryVC *acvc = [[AddCategoryVC alloc]init];

    acvc.delegate = self;
}
```

And finally, from the DelegateVC.m file, the delegate methods themselves:

```
#pragma mark - New category delegate methods

-(void)addCategoryDidSave:(WMMGCategory *)brandNewCategory
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)addCategoryDidCancel:(WMMGCategory *)categoryToDelete
{
    [categoryToDelete MR_deleteEntity];
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I admit up front that I might have made some dumbass typo or something, but I'd sure appreciate someone taking a look to see what I'm doing wrong.

**Edit, pursuant to @rdelmar's answer below:**

Here's the creation code for the instance of AddCategoryVC:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"CatSelectSegue"])
    {
        UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *catSelPPC = dvc.popoverPresentationController;
        if (catSelPPC)
        {
            catSelPPC.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"newCatSegue"])
    {
        UIViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *catNewPPC = dvc.popoverPresentationController;


        NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"newTransSegue"])
        {
            UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            AddCategoryVC *addCatVC = (AddCategoryVC *)navController.topViewController;
            addCatVC.delegate = self;
            WMMGCategory *addedCategory = (WMMGCategory *)[WMMGCategory MR_createInContext:localContext];
            addCatVC.brandNewCategory = addedCategory;
        }

        if (catNewPPC)
        {
            catNewPPC.delegate = self;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating an instance of AddCategoryVC in viewDidLoad that is not the one you have on screen (you never do anything with it, so it will be deallocated right after viewDidLoad goes out of scope). You need to get a reference to the instance you already have. I can't be specific about how to do that without knowing where you make your controllers and how they get on screen.

Comment: Please see edit for creation code. I think I see a problem (or at least not a solution) where I assign "self" as delegate as soon as it's created. Not sure how to get the reference. Please let me know if you need more info. Thanks!

Comment: @rattletrap99, the way you're doing it in prepareForSegue looks correct. You are getting the reference with AddCategoryVC *addCatVC = (AddCategoryVC *)navController.topViewController. What class is that code in?

Comment: Sorry, had to step away for a few. That code is in AddTransactionVC.m (the Delegate class). Which is where the activating button is, BTW.

Comment: @rattletrap99, ok, I don't see anything wrong then. If you log self.delegate in the cancelCategory: method in AddCategoryVC does it show you the instance of AddTransactionVC that should be the delegate?

Comment: I just this minute discovered the problem. See where it says "newCatSegue" in prepareForSegue? It should say the same thing in the nested if, but instead says "newTransSegue." I changed it and now it seems to work. A secondary issue is why I have the nested if there to begin with, so will also be looking at that. Thanks a million! The fix was kind of peripheral, but if your answer hadn't got me looking at that prepareForSegue method, I don't know when I'd have found the solution. Accepted and up voted!

Comment: I just un-nested the if statement and everything still works. Thanks again!